# How to display files with spaces in name when iterating array contents

Tags: bash

I have written a simple script that checks the content of a zip file against the contents of a control file.

It works well but it fails with errors (that are not really there) when I receives files that have spaces in them. This is a snippet of my code (`name` is an array created to process ZIP files in bulk).

```
echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` List ZIP file contents."                                          
LIST_Array=(`/usr/bin/unzip -l $name | head -n -2|tail -n +4 | sort -r | awk '{print $4}'`)
LISTlen=${#LIST_Array[*]}
#iterate array to 1) build report and 2) look for control file
echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` Iterate array to 1) build report and 2) look for control files."  
echo -e "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` Files in ZIP file: $name\n"                                    >> $name.report.out
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#LIST_Array[@]} ; i++ ))
do
    echo -e "${LIST_Array[$i]}"      >> $name.report.out
done
```

The list of files in the ZIP is captured into `$name.report.out` and then compared against the contents of the control file itself.

How can I correctly display files with spaces? I though the `echo -e` would help but it seemingly has not effect.

Thanks.

Comment: If `name` is really an array there, you are only getting the first element of it. To expand a shell array, express it as `"${array[@]}".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the zip file has files in it some of whose names have whitespace in them. In that case, when you list the files, awk '{ print $4 }' will not capture the entire filename. `read` is nice in that its last argument captures the rest of the line:

```
LIST_Array=()
while read length date time filename; do
    LIST_Array+=( "$filename" )
done < <(/usr/bin/unzip -qql "$name")
```

Comment: The problem is not `name`. It is `LIST_Array` where I unzip the zip file.

Comment: @Chris So you are saying the file names with spaces are the files *inside* the zip file?

Comment: I think you're using `name` for two different things here; as the array(?) containing the name(s) of the zip file(s) to read with `unzip`, and as the variable that `read` populates while reading the list of files inside the zip file.

Comment: @chepner that's a good catch. Thanks. (I've edited the answer, but for what it's worth, I suspect it would've worked in its original form – the old `name` would've been parsed before it got replaced.)

Comment: @kojiro: that is correct. The file names with spaces are the files inside the zip file.

Comment: Kojiro's suggestion took care of the space issue. Accepted and voted up. Thank you.